# Serial Port Comm with Arduino Device from Windows Store C# App

Tags: c#, windows-8, serial-port, arduino, windows-store-apps

I'm currently working on getting a Leonardo device recognized and communicating with my app over a serial port in C# for the Windows 8 App Store. I'm using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn312121(v=vs.85).aspx#step2 as a guide, in conjunction with http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/USB-CDC-Control-sample-5ba19caa to guide me.

I'm having problems however in the sense that my Arduino device isn't showing up despite me entering my PID/VID and Class/Subclass/Protocol so I feel I'm missing some steps and was hoping someone that has experience with this could point me to a more specific/granular example.

My device is an Arduino Leonardo and I'm running windows 8.1 using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, code is in C#

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What driver is the Arduino using for serial communication? It must use WinUSB.sys, not usbser.sys (which is the old one). I ran into this problem as well. Making a new driver for it is not particularly difficult, but you will likely need to go through a process of making a CAT and signing it yourself (which can be a bit of a hassle).

Comment: @NateDiamond Hey Nate, I just double checked and you are right, I am currently using the old usbser.sys driver. I'm completely new to Arduino/drivers/etc, do you have any resources you can point me to that you used when creating your new driver?

Comment: Sure! [Check this out.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) It looks really complicated, but it's about as easy as setting a couple of fields, such as the manufacturer's name (you can make one up) and the VID/PID. Now, you need to install that driver. You can either disable driver signing verification or [sign it yourself](http://www.pixcl.com/Signing_Windows_8_Drivers.htm). It seems scary, but it's also pretty easy. Install the Driver toolkit, use Inf2Cat, Make a cert, use SignTool, install the cert to TrustedInstallers and Root. Install driver

Comment: If you do make your own cert and install it to root, *protect that cert like crazy*. Encrypt it, store it somewhere, possibly even just delete it and make a new one each time. If someone gets a copy of it, they can install arbitrary drivers to your computer. Bad news. But, if you protect it, then it should be good to go. Also, not all parts of that guide are 100% required, but it goes over all of the important points. (Again: Inf2Cat, MakeCert, SignTool, Install Certs, Install Driver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to answer this as not currently possible. I ended up writing a desktop WPF application using metro UI/UX guidelines. Between that and ClickOnce deployment the store app feel is fairly well recreated, despite the store being ideal.

I sincerely hope that Microsoft decides to support this in the near future, the Metro SDK is really nice and I would love to eventually port it.

Answer (score 0):

Just general thoughts on regular windows applications (not aware of W8 AppStore):
Might help or might not, in the second case, sorry for wasting your time...

To get a "regular COM" device in Windows, without any additional drivers, you should make the device appear as USB Communication Device Class (aka CDC) - this is, among others, done via the appropriate class/subclass/protocol. The VID/PID don't care. This means the device should provide CDC/ACM USB descriptors to the enumerating USB host (windows) and implement the required endpoints and commands - supposedly there is already something existing for your board and you downloaded the firmware to it, right? You might want to try to connect such configured device to windows and after successful enumeration, new COM port should appear. If you program regular application, you just connect to such COM port via SerialPort class instance, no matter it is provided via USB subsystem... If this works, you should be able to start the AppStore part (where I have no clue how to help).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've already got it working for desktop applications as it shows up under Comm/Ports, but my issue stems from the Windows Store libraries being different/more strict and my Desktop App solution doesn't work/isn't available. More information is always welcome! If it doesn't help me it might help someone that stumbles on this at a later time.